# typescript Build:Operator '==' cant be applied to type '"="' and '"{"'

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I ran into this interesting compile error which seem to me that Typescript is too smart for its own good.

```
private _currentToken: string;
....
private ParseKeyValuePair(): KeyValuePair<string, any>
{
    let key = this.RemoveBracketAndQuote(this._currentToken);
    this.NextToken();
    if (this._currentToken != "=")
        throw "Expect = sign but got " + this._currentToken;

    this.NextToken();
    let val: any = this.RemoveBracketAndQuote(this._currentToken);
    if (this._currentToken == "{") //Compile error on this line
        val = this.ParseObject();

    return new KeyValuePair(key, val);
}
```

This is a quick and dirty parser I wrote and it works perfectly well when compiled with TS 1.7

After I upgraded TS to 2.6 I'm getting this compile error.

> Build:Operator '==' cant be applied to type '“=”' and '“{”'

To me it seems like TS sees the first if statement and determine that `this._currentToken` must be string `"="` or else exception would be thrown. But in fact `this._currentToken` would get changed by `this.NextToken()` call and TS did not anticipate that.

Is it a Typescript compiler bug or am I doing something stupid here?

Edit: I am able to make a minimum reproducible example

```
class Test
{
    private property: string;

    private changeProperty(): void
    {
        this.property = "bar";
    }

    private TestFunc(): void
    {
        if (this.property != "foo")
            throw "bad";

        this.changeProperty();
        if (this.property == "bar") //compile error
            console.log("good");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typescript feature, although in this case it looks like it hurts more than it helps. Typescript has a concept of "type narrowing", where if you restrict a variables type along some code paths, typescript will use that narrowed type farther down the line. So for your snippet, the line:

```
if (this._currentToken != "=")
    throw "Expect = sign but got " + this._currentToken;
```

Means that if the current token is anything except the value `"="`, then the method will throw and the code will not advance past that. Thus, if the code HAS advanced past that, the value must be `"="`. In other words, that line of code has narrowed your type to be the string literal "=".

Then you have the line:

```
if (this._currentToken == "{") //Compile error on this line
    val = this.ParseObject();
```

Which produces an error, since typescript believes your `this._currentToken` has the value `"="`, which is not equal to `"{"`. So (in typescript's mind), this if statement is always false, and it wants to save you some trouble.

The issue is that you call a method `nextToken`, which I assume mutates the `_.currentToken` value. Sadly typescript isn't aware of that.

**So you have a few options**

- You can add a comment: `//@ts-ignore` right above the offending line to silence typescript.
- You can cast your value as a string, eg: `if ((this._currentToken as string) == "{") ...`

Either way, you'll have to manually give typescript a hint that it's inference is not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use type guards to inform the type system of the change you're describing:

```
class Test
{
    property: string;

    private changeProperty(): this is this & { property: "bar" }
    {
        this.property = "bar";
        return true;
    }

    private TestFunc(): void
    {
        if (this.property != "foo")
            throw "bad";

        if (this.changeProperty()) {
            if (this.property == "bar") // no compile error
                console.log("good");
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little hacky, but it works.